# angular quick click during scope varialble apply issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular application when i am click on a button then it will disabled will in few milli seconds but during that time user again click on same button then issue functionality run again like api call etc.

Comment: @NikunjSardhara any solution for this to prevent because i need to use ng-click at there, thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you could do something like this:

```
var buttonDisabled = false;

$scope.myClickFunction = function () {

    if (!buttonDisabled) {
        buttonDisabled = true;
        MyService.MakeMyNetworkCall().then(function () {
            buttonDisabled = false;
        });
    }

}
```

In this case, as soon as the button is clicked, it is disabled in your controller, and additional clicks will prevent it from making additional network calls.  Then you return a promise from your network call and only re-enable the button when the network call completes.  Additionally, if you exposed the `buttonDisabled` property on `$scope`, then you could use it to disable your button in the view once the `$apply` cycle had caught up.

Comment: actully i need to add mulitple item at there so issue arise so need to update disabled flag on api call response.

Comment: "need to add multiple item at there" -- please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: <button type='button'  class='btn btn-default' name='button' ng-click='addUrl(url)' ng-disabled="isApiCall">
                <i class='fa fa-plus'></i>
              </button>

Comment: @ChandraKantPaliwal - I'm afraid that does not provide enough context for me.  Perhaps it would be best if you included your code in your question, so that StackOverflow users have a better sense of how to assist you.  Otherwise we can only provide very general solutions.

Comment: @anied when fast clicking on ng-click, in case buttonDisabled variable is taking few mili secons to udpate to true at that time buttonDisabled property not enable in view. So user can create multiple records by doing fast double clicks.

Comment: @GiteshPurbia -- yes, but the whole point of my solution is that the button need not be disabled _in the view,_ -- instead the Controller will keep track of the flag.  It is not subject to the delay of the `$apply` cycle, and will be set instantaneously, so the first time the button is clicked the `buttonDisabled` flag is set.  Any subsequent clicks _will_ call `myClickFunction`, but it will be unable to enter the `if` block.  Only once the network call completes and the callback in the `.then` restores the flag to `false` will clicks on the button be able to trigger a new network call.

Comment: @anied yes we had already tried this solution. Lets keep the buttonDisabled variable as var buttonDisabled instead of controller or scope variable.

Comment: @GiteshPurbia - sure, but my point is that you can do both-- if it is exposed on $scope, it can still be used in the manner above-- as a gatekeeper preventing additional/superfluous calls to the API-- _and_ it can serve to display the button as disabled in the UI.  Even if it takes a few milliseconds to activate, it doesn't matter because it is also being used as a gatekeeper in the controller JS scope.  Regardless, the above solution should be sufficient for the issue as I understand it-- if something more specific is needed, I recommend adding some code to the question.